# Removing 1st instance of a specific number from a Queue

Tags: c++, queue

I have created a program that will remove every instance of the inputted number from the queue but cannot figure out how to modify it so that it will only remove the first instance of said number.

Here is my program as of now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>


using namespace std;


int main(){
    queue<int> q;

    int size;
    cout << "Enter the size of the queue: ";
    cin >> size;
    int val;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << "Enter a value to insert into the queue: ";
        cin >> val;
        q.push(val);

    }

    int value;
    bool found = false;
    queue<int> temp;
    queue<int> printQueue;
    cout << "Which value would you like to remove: ";
    cin >> value;

    while (!q.empty()){
        if (q.front() == value)
            q.pop();
        else{
            temp.push(q.front());
            q.pop();
        }
    }
    q = temp;
    printQueue = q;

while (!printQueue.empty()){
        cout << printQueue.front() << " ";
        printQueue.pop();
    }

}
```

How would I modify this? I was thinking of putting a bool value in the while loop that removes all but then it would kick out once it finds one and not finish copying over the rest of the queue to the temporary one.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Exit the `while (!q.empty())` loop early whenever you've removed an element. Then add another loop to transfer any remaining elements from `q` to `temp`. You should really consider using a more appropriate container though.

Comment: studying for a test so have to learn this one! But thanks, will try that

Answer (score 0):

If requirements permit, you can use a double ended queue, which allows iteration and modification.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>

int value;

std::deque<int> q;

//insert numbers
//define value

//find first instance of value
auto iter = std::find(std::begin(q), std::end(q), value);

//if found, erase it
if (iter != std::end(q)) {
  q.erase(iter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are very close, you could just add a verification in your while loop to pop your element only once.

```
int main(){
queue<int> q;

int size;
cout << "Enter the size of the queue: ";
cin >> size;
int val;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cout << "Enter a value to insert into the queue: ";
    cin >> val;
    q.push(val);

}

int value;
bool found = false;
queue<int> temp;
queue<int> printQueue;
cout << "Which value would you like to remove: ";
cin >> value;

while (!q.empty()){
    if (q.front() == value && found == false)
        q.pop();
        found = true;
    else{
        temp.push(q.front());
        q.pop();
    }
}
q = temp;
printQueue = q;

while (!printQueue.empty()){
    cout << printQueue.front() << " ";
    printQueue.pop();
    }

}
```